# Pegar url da rota acessada em NodeJS

Tags: node.js, servidor, request, https, response

Preciso saber qual foi a url externa que o usuario acessou no meu servidor.
O meu script funciona bem quando a rota é "localhost", más não funciona para saber qual a url quando o dominio não é o mesmo que este. Preciso que quando for digitado "https://www.google.com.br" o meu servidor print no console que a url foi esta.

```js
const url = require("url");
const app = require("express")()
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('keys/key.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('keys/key.cert', 'utf8');

app.use((req, res) => {
    console.log(req) //AQUI ELE SÓ MOSTRA AS ROTAS QUE COMEÇAM COM LOCALHOST
})

var serverssl = https.createServer({key: privateKey, cert: certificate}, app).listen(443);
```

Comment: Uma requisição `http` não inclui dados de qual página o usuário estava antes de acessar sua página. A única forma de obter alguma informação sobre a atividade do usuário é rastreando os cookies do usuário por meio de serviços como o Google Analytics por exemplo. Se você quer saber para onde o usuário está indo após sair do seu site, também não é possível, pois a requisição não é enviada para o seu servidor.

Comment: Não quero a pagina que ele estava antes, e sim a pagina que ele acessar no exato momento... Más acho que o node é incapaz de me dar os dados de uma URL https

Comment: consegue explicar melhor

Answer (score 0):

> Preciso que quando for digitado "https://www.google.com.br" o meu
> servidor print no console que a url foi esta.

Não é que o Node.js que é incapaz.

É simplesmente impossível extrair esse tipo de informação pelo fato de que a requisição vai ser feita para os servidores da Google e não para o seu.